# Are solutions to the particle in a (finite) box problem orthonormal?

Tags: hilbert-space, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-states

Solving the particle in a box problem is fairly straight-forward for both, the finite and infinite potential well. While it is well known that the solutions to the infinite potential well must be orthogonal, it is not so obvious whether that should be the case for a potential well with finite height.

[image: Finite potential]

I tried to find references in which orthogonality of those states is shown, but I was not very successful so far. Does anyone here know how one could show orthogonality of these states and/or tell me about papers in which this property has been established?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory) “The normalized eigenfunctions form an orthonormal basis...”

Comment: Just to extend the previous comment a little: the eigenfunctions of any Hermitian operator are mutually orthogonal when they have different eigenvalues. Where two or more have the same eigenvalue then one can find mutually orthogonal linear superpositions which are also orthogonal to all the other eigenfunctions. In this way the set of eigenfunctions of a Hermitian operator can always form an orthonormal set.

Comment: I can see how this explains why eigenstates in an infinite square well must be orthonormal, but a particle in a finite square well faces a discontinuity at the boundary. These discontinuities will show up in the Hamiltonian (since the Hamiltonian depends on the potential), s.t. the wavefunctions must satisfy different Hamiltonians at different positions. Can someone elaborate on how Sturm-Liouville theory still holds in that case?

Comment: . @AndrewSteane

Comment: Ah you have a slight muddle there. There is just one Hamiltonian here. Its functional form may be specified in terms of different behaviours at different values of $x$, but it is still a single overall function. It is furthermore Hermitian, so its eigenstates are orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time-independent Schrodinger equation is in the class of real second-order linear ordinary differential equations covered by 19th-century [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory). The eigenfunctions of such equations are orthogonal with respect to an appropriate inner product on the function space.

So one does not have to prove orthogonality for each potential one is interested in, such as a finite square well. It is a general result for all potentials.

Comment: Please see my comment above

Comment: I don’t know the mathematical details of how Sturm-Liouville theory applies to a discontinuous potential; I just know that it does. My guess is that you can consider the square well to be the limit of a smooth potential. Orthogonality certainly applies for any smooth potential arbitrarily close to a square well. By some kind of continuity argument, it applies in the limit as well. In general, this is the kind of thing that mathematicians, not physicists, worry about. If you want a detailed answer, I suggest asking on Math SE.